# React useEffect dependency disrupts value passing

Tags: reactjs

I need some explanation regarding useEffect dependencies. In this example, I type the number and it returns that number in minutes and seconds. Limit < 60 works good, but limit > 60 does not. It transforms the minutes, but that value is not passed to setSeconds. The trick is that all this works fine when I remove the [limit] dependency, but because this is a part of bigger function, I want to keep it. How does having the dependency disrupt the value from passing to setSeconds?

```
    const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState("");
    const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState("");
    const [limit, setLimit] = useState("");
    useEffect(() => {
      if (limit < 60) {
          setSeconds(limit);
          setMinutes(0);
      }
      if (limit >= 60 && limit < 3600) {
          setMinutes(Math.floor(limit / 60));
          setSeconds(limit - (60 * minutes //minutes does not pass));
      }
      }, [limit]);
    function handleChange (e) {
        if (limit === 0) {
            setLimit(null);
        }
        setLimit(e.target.value)
    }
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>{String(minutes).padStart(2, "0")}:{String(seconds).padStart(2, "0")}</h1>
            <h1>{String(limit).padStart(2, "0")}</h1>
          <input type="text" name="settime" value={limit} onChange={handleChange} />
        </div>
      )
```

Comment: The new value of `minutes` isn't available until the *next* time the component gets rendered and `useState` gets called. Why not assign e.g. `const newMinutes = Math.floor(limit / 60);` and use that in both cases?

Comment: This will save you from most of the mistakes you are making in your ```useEffect``` hook https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setState` is an async function, it will wait for the best possible time to update to not trigger any unnecessary re-renders.

So your new `minutes` value isn't available right after calling `setMinutes`:

```
if (limit >= 60 && limit < 3600) {
  setMinutes(Math.floor(limit / 60));
  setSeconds(limit - (60 * minutes //minutes is still the previous value));
}
```

This is what React will do.

1. Call `setState`
2. Execute whatever is left of your function.
3. Execute `setState`
4. Re-render.

To solve this you can declare a new variable with your new value like this:

```
if (limit >= 60 && limit < 3600) {
  const newMinutes = Math.floor(limit / 60);
  setMinutes(newMinutes);
  setSeconds(limit - (60 * newMinutes));
}
```

This way you don't rely on the stateful value to execute your function properly.